# Android BluetoothLEGatt BLE not staying connected to device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I am running the [sample BluetoothLeGatt app from google](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html) and having trouble keeping my device connected. I feel like I am having random behavior a little bit. The bluetooth doesn't usually doesn't connect on the first try (so usually I almost want to say never.)

About 50% of the time when I press the connect button, the app says that the state is Connected. However, the hardware device has an LED that is supposed to light up when it is connected and it doesn't light up. Then 5 or 6 seconds later it goes to disconnected. I suspect that it is connecting for a split second and then disconnecting and the app just doesn't get the memo for a while. Here is the logcat:

```
D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6, auto: false
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=60edb0ed-90de-4d7d-b4d0-690bcc359fb7
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=10
D/BluetoothLeService: Trying to create a new connection.
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=10 device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6
I/BluetoothLeService: Connected to GATT server.
D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: 54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6
I/BluetoothLeService: Attempting to start service discovery:true
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetService() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetService() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetService() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00002a02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00002a03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetDescriptor() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetDescriptor() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onGetDescriptor() - Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 UUID=00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6 Status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=10 device=54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6
I/BluetoothLeService: Disconnected from GATT server.
```

Maybe 10% of the time I hit the connect button and don't see anything happen:

```
D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 54:4A:16:2F:3C:F6, auto: false
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=7dbe26bc-4cee-48d2-9f47-59af4edb33bb
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=133 clientIf=0
I/BluetoothLeService: Disconnected from GATT server.
D/BluetoothLeService: Trying to create a new connection.
```

and maybe 30% of the time it actually connects.

It's possible that it's a hardware/firmware problem. Although I have no problems when connecting to the device with my iPhone, so I want to conclude that the android code is broke somewhere. I could post all the BLE code but I literally just downloaded the sample so that I knew it was nothing that I broke.

**Edit**: for those keeping track of my math. The last 10% of the time the app doesn't find *anything* when it scans, and I have to restart the app.

**Edit**: I've downloaded and tried 2 other BLE apps from the play store and get the same connection problems as I do as the google sample BLE app. Is there some setting that android's implementation of BLE needs to have that would be different from iOS?

Comment: Hi,Did you found root cause of this issue?
I am facing the same issue but not able to get reason for the same.

Comment: There are a bunch of things. I've read a lot that the android BLE sdk's are just bad because every hardware manufacturer uses different BLE chips so it's hard to have a reliable universal android BLE sdk. Another problem was that our chip wasn't calibrating to the right baud. I guess there is a 10% variance in the software clock which was causing us to drop packets. (I think that's correct-I'm not the hardware guy)

Comment: https://atmosphere.anaren.com/wiki/Android_Issues_With_Bluetooth_Low_Energy

Comment: https://github.com/iDevicesInc/SweetBlue/wiki/Android-BLE-Issues

Comment: I can slim down my project a little bit and send you the code I ended up going with if you want. Basically I just added a bunch of watchdog timers so that if any step failed or took too long it would retry that step. Basically just super defensive programming.

Comment: Hi @Chase, thank you for providing details.You are right, it is due to calibration issue.It is now happening vary rarely.Thank you for the help and support

Comment: No problem. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @ChaseRoberts, I would appreciate if you could post the code you used to solve this issue as an answer, for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: After struggling with this for months. I went back to google's example, and tried not to stray from their code at all. They have a line or two where they check if the device was connected before and automatically connect. At first, I was removing that line thinking that I could start new every time, but some phones just won't connect the first try, so you need those reconnect lines.

Answer (score 2):

Try using: 
BluetoothDevice.connectGatt(Context context, boolean autoConnect, BluetoothGattCallback callback, int transport)

with TRANSPORT_LE as transport.

That did the trick for me.